# Find Radius of Curvature

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

A uniform chain of mass per unit length labda is suspended in the vertical plane from point-A and point-B as shown in the figure. Length of chain is L. Find the radius of curvature at point A and point B[image]

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) for "check my work" questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shape of the rope will be a [Catenary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary#Mathematical_description). If we express the shape as a function of x and assume one of point A as origin it will be a hyperbolic function and the constant $a$ is given by plugging the point B. Then we can use the radius of curvature formula to fin the radius at any point. For $y=f(x)$
$$\rho (x)=\dfrac{|1+f'^2|^{\frac{3}{2}}}{|f''|}  $$